# Flutter-developing kiosk app for both android and ios(?)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, kiosk-mode

I recently started coding with flutter, and i wish to develop some sort of kiosk app for both platforms (ios and android).
I know that as for android, a thing like that can be achieved (for example by building a custom launcher), but for ios i didn’t find anything regarding the subject.
To be clear: I’m talking about creating an app with multiple ‘allowed’ apps, which the user can not exit from (until the app tells him to, programmatically).
Is there a way to achieve that? Would like some information or guiding lines on the subject.

Comment: For what it's worth, Android has a kiosk mode with no need to do any hacky tricks like a custom launcher.  For iOS, some quick Google searching suggests it's called "Guided Access", but I'm not particularly familiar with the setup of either.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That is why i asked, because guided access let you lock only the screen on the specific activity that you’re currently doing. And that is not what im looking for, that’s why im introduced in creating a new app, for example like“Hexnode” for ios lets you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new plugin that you can use to perform this kind of function. Try using the [kiosk_mode](https://pub.dev/packages/kiosk_mode), it provides helper methods for working with Lock Task mode on Android and Guided Access mode on iOS. [Here](https://pub.dev/packages/kiosk_mode/example) is an example provided in the documentation that you can follow.

For a smooth development of your kiosk app, I suggest to explore [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs). It provides a variety of tools and services to create quality apps.